# Why undefined method `expect' when checking in at_exit hook

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber

I am trying to check the exitstatus of a command through the below code. It is resulting in an error --->undefined method 'expect'

```
require 'rspec'
require 'rspec/expectations'

at_exit do

 \`cat /etc/redhat-release\`

  expect($?.exitstatus).to eq(0)

end
```

Can any one please help me in solving this problem

Comment: Remove escaping backslashes in the first place and please share the exact error message then.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is suppose be a test case based on rspec, and you are mixing it with normal ruby code.

In order to test your code with rspec you need to wrap the test scenarios and cases inside a `describe` and `it` block, only then you'll have access to the `expect` method, like so:

```
# test.rb
require 'rspec'
require 'rspec/expectations'

describe 'Test exit status' do
  it "check status" do
    `cat /etc/redhat-release`
    expect($?.exitstatus).to eq(0)
  end
end
```

and you run this code with rspec command line, like: `rspec test.rb`

The code you had before, was using the `at_exit` block. This is only called when you exit the program, or receive a signal for it to be killed.